# Get project.build.directory from MavenProject?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

`MavenProject.getBaseDir()` returns the directory of the pom.xml file. How do I get ${project.build.directory} using `MavenProject`? I believe users are allowed to redefine this property so simply adding "target" to getBaseDir() won't work.

Comment: Do you want to use that in your mojo?

Comment: Are you trying to access target directory or target/classes?

Comment: @Gaurav, the "target" directory, not "target/classes".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MavenProject.getBuild().getDirectory()

Comment: getBuild() returns a Build object and getDirectory() is inherited from the BuildBase class.  It's easy to overlook in the javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a property in a way

```
@parameter default-value="${project.build.directory}"
```

This will be replaced with proper value.

Second - you can check

MavenProject.getModel().getBuild().getDirectory()

It's not tested, though.